# Localize an Angular 11 library

Tags: angular, localization, internationalization, libraries, angular11

The [Angular i18n docs](https://angular.io/guide/i18n) are clear about localizing an app, but it does not say anything about libraries.

`ng add @angular/localize` does not modify `angular.json`, and `ng extract-i18n` fails with the following errors :

**Missing extract-i18n in `angular.json`**

`An unhandled exception occurred: No projects support the 'extract-i18n' target.`

**Adding `extract-i18n` target in `angular.json`**

`Data path "" should have required property 'browserTarget'.`

How do I generate a `messages.xlf` file for my library ?

Answer (score 1):

As of March 2021, this is [not yet supported](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/17140#issuecomment-726080457).

There is [a workaround](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/29536#issuecomment-775162817) however :

First install `@angular/localize` like you would for a regular app :

```sh
ng add @angular/localize
```

In `package.json`, add the following script to **scan the built files for localized strings** :

```json
"i18n": "localize-extract -r . -s \"dist/efp-widgets/fesm2015/*.js\" -f xlf -o messages.xlf"
```

Note that `localize-extract` comes from `@angular/localize`;

If using `$localize` in TypeScript, don't forget to register `@angular/localize/init` in `public-api.ts` :

```js
import '@angular/localize/init'
```

Then add the `i18n` script to your main build script in `package.json` :

```json
"build": "ng build && npm run i18n"
```

Comment: Careful adding `import '@angular/localize/init'` elsewhere in the codebase (to get rid of IDE warnings, for example). In my case it resulted in $localize translations not being loaded without any indication as to what went wrong.